# Failure installation on Limbo VM

Tags: 22.04, virtualization

Ubuntu Jammy Jelly failed to install on Limbo Virtual Machine (Limbo Emulator) while Kali Linux's installation successful. What is the reason behind and solution for the problem?

Comment: What model device are you trying to install Ubuntu on?

Comment: Samsung Galaxy M30s 6Gb ram